# Fix text position in table

Tags: html, css, templates, html-table

I have a simple problem while putting text in multiple table!
please have a look at the code. In this code look at the text called "why it is in middle" always stay in middle I can't put them in top of that table!

CODE

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>welcome</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some code here </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>php script here </td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td width="50%">why it is in middle </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So how  can I put it in the top of table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the css attribute `vertical-align: top;`. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUYJ3/).

Answer (score 0):

There is also valign, if you wanted to use an inline table attribute.

```
<td valign="top">This will be at the top</td>
```